# “Stuff and 'For Xml Path'” or UNION to exclude duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, union, for-xml-path, stuff

This is further progress of question here: [how to use "Stuff and 'For Xml Path'" to unite rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231757/how-to-use-stuff-and-for-xml-path-to-unite-rows-in-table)

I have 3 tables - invoices, positions and accounts which build common table by SELECT as specified in result below. I need to exclude duplicate rows which appear due to different accounts for same invoices. I think it can be solved by “Stuff and 'For Xml Path'” and/or by UNION, but I don't really know how to do that.

Please assist with this issue. Thank You in advance.

Here's dbfiddle with DL and sample data population: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6401c2886a24b21239dade27e8c549ec

*Using DevExpress dashboard designer based on SQL Server 2016.*

**Query:**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
invoice VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
);
INSERT invoices(invoice, id) 
VALUES ('ty20210110', 1);
INSERT invoices(invoice, id) 
VALUES ('ty20210111', 2);
INSERT invoices(invoice, id) 
VALUES ('ty20210112', 3);

CREATE TABLE positions
(
position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
quantity INT NOT NULL,
price INT NOT NULL,
summ INT NOT NULL, 
invoice INT NOT NULL,
);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000001', 2, 100, 200, 1);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000002', 3, 100, 300, 2);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000003', 1, 250, 250, 2);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000004', 2, 120, 240, 1);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000005', 4, 100, 400, 1);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000006', 3, 100, 300, 1001);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000007', 5, 80, 400, 3);
INSERT positions(position, quantity, price, summ, invoice) 
VALUES ('p1000008', 5, 100, 500, 3);

CREATE TABLE accounts
(
account INT NOT NULL,
invoice INT NOT NULL,
);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (01, 2);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (02, 2);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (03, 1);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (04, 3);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (05, 1);
INSERT accounts(account, invoice) 
VALUES (06, 3);
-- DDL and sample data population, end


SELECT
positions.position, positions.quantity, positions.price, positions.summ,
invoices.invoice,
accounts.account

FROM
positions
INNER JOIN
invoices invoices ON invoices.id = positions.invoice
INNER JOIN
accounts accounts ON invoices.id = accounts.invoice
```

**Result:**

| position | quantity | price | summ | invoice | account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1000001 | 2 | 100 | 200 | in20210110 | 3 |
| p1000001 | 2 | 100 | 200 | in20210110 | 5 |
| p1000002 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210111 | 1 |
| p1000002 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210111 | 2 |
| p1000003 | 1 | 250 | 250 | in20210111 | 1 |
| p1000003 | 1 | 250 | 250 | in20210111 | 2 |
| p1000004 | 2 | 120 | 240 | in20210110 | 3 |
| p1000004 | 2 | 120 | 240 | in20210110 | 5 |
| p1000005 | 4 | 100 | 400 | in20210110 | 3 |
| p1000005 | 4 | 100 | 400 | in20210110 | 5 |
| p1000006 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210110 | 3 |
| p1000006 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210110 | 5 |
| p1000007 | 5 | 80 | 400 | in20210112 | 4 |
| p1000007 | 5 | 80 | 400 | in20210112 | 6 |
| p1000008 | 5 | 100 | 500 | in20210112 | 4 |
| p1000008 | 5 | 100 | 500 | in20210112 | 6 |

**Required result 1:**

| position | quantity | price | summ | invoice | account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1000001 | 2 | 100 | 200 | in20210110 | 3, 5 |
| p1000004 | 2 | 120 | 240 | in20210110 | 3, 5 |
| p1000005 | 4 | 100 | 400 | in20210110 | 3, 5 |
| p1000006 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210110 | 3, 5 |
| p1000002 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210111 | 1, 2 |
| p1000003 | 1 | 250 | 250 | in20210111 | 1, 2 |
| p1000007 | 5 | 80 | 400 | in20210112 | 4, 6 |
| p1000008 | 5 | 100 | 500 | in20210112 | 4, 6 |

**Required result 2:**

| position | quantity | price | summ | invoice | account 1 | account 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1000001 | 2 | 100 | 200 | in20210110 | 3 | 5 |
| p1000004 | 2 | 120 | 240 | in20210110 | 3 | 5 |
| p1000005 | 4 | 100 | 400 | in20210110 | 3 | 5 |
| p1000006 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210110 | 3 | 5 |
| p1000002 | 3 | 100 | 300 | in20210111 | 1 | 2 |
| p1000003 | 1 | 250 | 250 | in20210111 | 1 | 2 |
| p1000007 | 5 | 80 | 400 | in20210112 | 4 | 6 |
| p1000008 | 5 | 100 | 500 | in20210112 | 4 | 6 |

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? In Result2, how many columns do you need? 2? 100? 1000? @Larnu Result1 does have

Comment: hi, added that info, thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first resultset can be handled in two ways, depending on your version of SQL Server. Try the following examples in SSMS:

**Create Data**

```
DECLARE @invoices table (
    invoice VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, id INT NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO @invoices (invoice, id) VALUES 
    ( 'ty20210110', 1 ), ( 'ty20210111', 2 ), ( 'ty20210112', 3 );

DECLARE @positions table (
    position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, quantity INT NOT NULL, price INT NOT NULL, summ INT NOT NULL, invoice INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @positions ( position, quantity, price, summ, invoice ) VALUES
    ( 'p1000001', 2, 100, 200, 1 ),
    ( 'p1000002', 3, 100, 300, 2 ),
    ( 'p1000003', 1, 250, 250, 2 ),
    ( 'p1000004', 2, 120, 240, 1 ),
    ( 'p1000005', 4, 100, 400, 1 ),
    ( 'p1000006', 3, 100, 300, 1 ),
    ( 'p1000007', 5, 80, 400, 3 ),
    ( 'p1000008', 5, 100, 500, 3 );

DECLARE @accounts table (
    account INT NOT NULL, invoice INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @accounts ( account, invoice ) VALUES 
    ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 3, 1 ), ( 4, 3 ), ( 5, 1 ), ( 6, 3 );
```

**If you're using SQL Server 2017+**

```
SELECT
    positions.position,
    positions.quantity,
    positions.price,
    positions.summ,
    invoices.invoice,
    STRING_AGG ( accounts.account, ',' ) AS account
FROM @positions positions
INNER JOIN @invoices invoices 
    ON invoices.id = positions.invoice
INNER JOIN @accounts accounts 
    ON invoices.id = accounts.invoice
GROUP BY
    position, quantity, price, summ, invoices.invoice
ORDER BY
    invoice;
```

**For Pre-SQL Server 2017**

```
SELECT
    positions.position,
    positions.quantity,
    positions.price,
    positions.summ,
    invoices.invoice,
    acct.account
FROM @positions positions
INNER JOIN @invoices invoices 
    ON invoices.id = positions.invoice
INNER JOIN @accounts accounts 
    ON invoices.id = accounts.invoice
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF ( (
        SELECT ',' + CAST ( a.account AS varchar(50) ) AS "text()"
        FROM @accounts a
        WHERE
            a.invoice = invoices.id
        FOR XML PATH ( '' )
    ), 1, 1, '' ) AS account
) AS acct
GROUP BY
    position, quantity, price, summ, invoices.invoice, acct.account
ORDER BY
    invoice;
```

Both queries return

```
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+---------+
| position | quantity | price | summ |  invoice   | account |
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+---------+
| p1000001 |        2 |   100 |  200 | ty20210110 | 3,5     |
| p1000004 |        2 |   120 |  240 | ty20210110 | 3,5     |
| p1000005 |        4 |   100 |  400 | ty20210110 | 3,5     |
| p1000006 |        3 |   100 |  300 | ty20210110 | 3,5     |
| p1000002 |        3 |   100 |  300 | ty20210111 | 1,2     |
| p1000003 |        1 |   250 |  250 | ty20210111 | 1,2     |
| p1000007 |        5 |    80 |  400 | ty20210112 | 4,6     |
| p1000008 |        5 |   100 |  500 | ty20210112 | 4,6     |
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+---------+
```

The second resultset you requested gets considerably more complicated and requires the use of the XML datatype. The following example makes liberal assumptions of your data, most notably that only two accounts are expected. Having said that, you can expand the `[account n]` columns in the `PIVOT` as necessary without having to resort to dynamic SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    positions.position,
    positions.quantity,
    positions.price,
    positions.summ,
    invoices.invoice
    , x.*
FROM @positions positions
INNER JOIN @invoices invoices 
    ON invoices.id = positions.invoice
INNER JOIN @accounts accounts 
    ON invoices.id = accounts.invoice
OUTER APPLY (

    -- Create an XML account list --
    SELECT CAST ( (
        SELECT 
            'account ' + CAST ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY a.invoice ) AS varchar(50) ) AS id,
            a.account
        FROM @accounts a
        WHERE
            a.invoice = invoices.id
        FOR XML PATH ( 'data' ), ROOT ( 'accounts' )
    ) AS xml ) AS account_xml

) AS acct
OUTER APPLY (

    -- PIVOT the account details --
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            x.f.value( 'id[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) AS id,
            x.f.value( 'account[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) AS act
        FROM acct.account_xml.nodes( '//accounts/data' ) x(f)
    ) AS d
    PIVOT (
        MAX ( act ) FOR id IN ( [account 1], [account 2] )
    ) AS p

) AS x
ORDER BY
    invoice;
```

Returns

```
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| position | quantity | price | summ |  invoice   | account 1 | account 2 |
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| p1000001 |        2 |   100 |  200 | ty20210110 |         3 |         5 |
| p1000004 |        2 |   120 |  240 | ty20210110 |         3 |         5 |
| p1000005 |        4 |   100 |  400 | ty20210110 |         3 |         5 |
| p1000006 |        3 |   100 |  300 | ty20210110 |         3 |         5 |
| p1000002 |        3 |   100 |  300 | ty20210111 |         1 |         2 |
| p1000003 |        1 |   250 |  250 | ty20210111 |         1 |         2 |
| p1000007 |        5 |    80 |  400 | ty20210112 |         4 |         6 |
| p1000008 |        5 |   100 |  500 | ty20210112 |         4 |         6 |
+----------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, Your answer is great!

Comment: I don't know why but 2nd solution shows empty cells in my work query (http://prntscr.com/zytby7) but in dbfiddle works properly. You can check my full work query in dbfiddle here (just to see script, it definitely doesn't work there): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0eb928dcc1ba5b98300288abe84d5379

Comment: @user421875 is it possible the data used here doesn't match your data at work? Without having access to your actual data (that's not a request) it's nearly impossible to tell from a screenshot.

Comment: Hi! Maybe because we don't need to convert soome to varchars? http://prntscr.com/100nlcn

Comment: by the way, in my work table accounts may have more than 2 instances per same invoice, maybe this caused my problem with 2nd solution - we add only 2 account columns. Anyways, 1st solution is totally fit to my need, so thanx a lot again for it.